# How can I stop recalculation in specific range (Excel/certtain Sheet/)?

Tags: excel

I have problem with recalculation values in cells (Excel)
How can I stop shit process for specific range of cells ?

I thought to turn on "xlManual" for certain sheet, but MVB give me a mistake
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Calculation = xlManual

Shutdown for all Workbook - I tried, not comfortable decision

Can anybody tips me a better solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As far as I know, `Manual` affects whole workbook and it's not possible to make it only for a specific sheet. But if you are working on `Manual`, you can recalculate a specific sheet or the whole workbook.